# Sumproduct in VBA using tables

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image]

I've defined a table called `subtable`. I'm attempting to perform calculation in a more dynamic manner than defining `range` with the appropriate cells. 
However, the line below is throwing a `compile error`. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
Set tbl = Sheets("ASF").ListObjects("tblASF")
tbl.Resize Range("A1:C1200")

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
ws.Name = "Test"
tbl.Range.Copy Destination:=ws.Range("C1")
Set subtable = Sheets("Test").ListObjects(1)

Dim rate As Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet
rate = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(--(Range("subtable[Tye]") = "Standard"), Range("subtable[Amount]"), Range("subtable[Rate]")) / Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("subtable[Amount]"), "Standard")
```

Comment: Hey, I've decided to flag this question as 'too broad'. Your question is lacking 1) any sort of examples, 2) full code for the context, 3) the exact error message. Without that, we are only left guessing on how to help you

Comment: @Rawrplus I agree that the question lacks context, but there is no error message beyond the fact that it is a syntax error. The entire line is highlighted red, with no indication of why the compiler is rejecting it.

Comment: I believe this should be sufficient information now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using "subtable" in formulas (e.g.: `Range("subtable[Tye]")...`) to refer to the table pointed by your `subTable` object variable you set in `Set subtable = Sheets("Test").ListObjects(1)`, but it's not working that way

-> you have to actually *name* the table after "subtable"

```
Set subtable = ws.ListObjects(1)
subtable.Name = "subtable" '<- name the table after "subtable"
```

then you have to follow @chillin piece of advice about the use of SUMPRODUCT() worksheet function

the final code could be:

```
Dim tbl As ListObject, subtable As ListObject
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set tbl = Sheets("ASF").ListObjects("tblASF")
tbl.Resize Range("A1:C1200")

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
ws.Name = "Test"
tbl.Range.Copy Destination:=ws.Range("C1")

Set subtable = ws.ListObjects(1)
subtable.Name = "subtable"

Dim rate As Long
rate = Application.Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(--(subtable[Tye]=""Standard""),subtable[Amount],subtable[Rate])/SUMIF(subtable[Tye],""Standard"",subtable[Amount])")
```

BTW, be advised that `Dim rate As Long` will cut any `rate` below 1 to zero

Comment: Since vba can not handle `sumproduct()` do you have an idea of how I can more dynamically refer my condition for "standard". For instance I created an array variable `arr_type(1) = "Standard"`, but I can't simply substitute this array variable into the application.evaluate above. Will I have to evaluate the `arr_type(1)` variable in the sumproduct statement?

Answer (score 1):

- Use `Range("name of range here")` when accessing ranges (ignoring `[]` syntactic sugar for now) -- and best to include the parent workbook and worksheet name (which hold the range).
- I think there is a mistake in your formula. You haven't included a third argument for `SUMIF`, so the return value will be zero (meaning you'll get a division by 0 error even if your code is syntactically valid).
- I don't think you can use `SUMPRODUCT` in VBA like you can in a cell. More specifically, in VBA you can't double negate an array (`--`) to turn it into an array of `1`s and `0`s. You instead have to manually loop over the array and transform it into the required array (as far as I know).

You'll need to fix your divisor/denominator in your division (I've changed it to make my example work).

Assuming your `subtable` table is on worksheet `"Sheet1"`:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub SumproductInVBA()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Dim typeColumn As Variant
        typeColumn = .Range("subtable[Type]").Value2

        Dim rowIndex As Long
        For rowIndex = LBound(typeColumn, 1) To UBound(typeColumn, 1)
            If typeColumn(rowIndex, 1) = "Standard" Then
                typeColumn(rowIndex, 1) = 1
            Else
                typeColumn(rowIndex, 1) = 0
            End If
        Next rowIndex

        Dim someVariable As Double
        someVariable = Application.SumProduct(typeColumn, .Range("subtable[Amount]"), .Range("subtable[Rate]")) / Application.SumIf(.Range("subtable[Type]"), "Standard", .Range("subtable[Amount]"))

    End With

End Sub
```

Or, instead of the above, a shorter but slower way might be:

```
someVariable = Application.Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(--(subtable[Type]=""Standard""),subtable[Amount],subtable[Rate])/SUMIF(subtable[Type],""Standard"",subtable[Amount])")
```

The above worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1) `[ ]` are not the way to access elements in an array in VBA. Instead, `[x]` is roughly the same as `Evaluate("x")` hence something like `subtable[Amount]` is sort of like `subtable Evaluate("Amount")`, which would clearly make no sense.

2) `Type` is a reserved word

You haven't provided enough context to say much more.

Comment: thanks on the `[]`, I tried to use the `range` method but its still the same. `SumProduct(--(Range("subtable[Tye]") = "Standard"), Range("subtable[Amount]"), Range("subtable[Rate]"))`